# Use Windows font in css SEGOE UI - is that allowed?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is it allowed to use:
"font-family: Segoe UI, Trebuchet MS, Lucide grande, sans-serif"

And just rely on the font thats already installed on the system. Including "ROBOTO" on any android device...

I would like to go away from google-fonts (Open sans), as it is causing data-protection problems in EU, and is also blocking website speed (CLS). Whatever.. I think its stupid to download a font.

I know it will look slightly different on Windows and Mac Systems, - but anyway it does look different on Android devices all the time, so let the Mac use Trebuchet MS an I am fine with that. It will not destroy the whole design.

I just would like to use "Segoe UI" if it is available on a Windows System (and it is on 99,9% of them anyway)
I do not offer it for download or safe it somewhere.

Is that legal?

I found the standard-web fonts (Arial, Verdana,...) are always missing a semibold weight, thats why I dislike to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal if you don't upload it on you site, if you just specify like font-family: Segoe UI, Trebuchet MS, Lucide grande, sans-serif its legal

If you want place font to your site (upload to your server) for all users (not only if they have it on PC) you need to buy [Web License](https://www.fonts.com/content/microsoft-typography) for it